# Run Node JS server without port number

Tags: node.js

Can we run our node application without specifying any port number. And if we can do that so what are the ways to achieve that.

Comment: No, every server (socket) has to be bound to some port.

Comment: If you define port number as 80 browsers can use direct links within port number 80. http://localhost:80 -> http://localhost

Comment: What do you mean without a port number? Do you mean without typing port number in the browser? Do you mean not connected to TCP/IP at all? There are many ways to interpret the phrase "without port number"

Comment: server.listen(port,hostname) here if we dont provide port number

Answer (score 0):

You do need a port number. A "port" is basically a mapping that will allow the OS to forward the incoming network packets to a specific process. So a server with no port is useless (or not a server).

What you can do instead, in order to find a port dynamically, is to use a module like `portfinder`.

As an example you can do this:

```
const express = require('express')
const portfinder = require('portfinder');
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ok: 1})
}) 

async function main() {
  const port = await portfinder.getPortPromise()
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
  })
}

main()
```